# Mysql order by in a char datatype with combination of numbers and characters

Tags: mysql, sorting

In a mysql table field `player_number` accept 3 char - It may accept numbers only, alphabets only or a combination of both with maximum 3 letters.
Table have entry like as follows,

```
 TR 
 11
 1
 2
 222
 A
 AA
```

Is there any quick way to display sorted "player_number" result as follows,

Preferred order

```
 1
 2
 11
 222
 A
 AA
 TR
```

Alternative:

```
  A
  AA
  TR
  1
  2
  11
  222
```

Comment: what's wrong with `order by`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In order to get the first preferred order:** (Number first then letters)

```
SELECT 
*
FROM YOUR_TABLE
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN player_number REGEXP '[0-9]+' THEN CAST(player_number AS UNSIGNED) END , player_number
```

---

**In order to get the alternative preferred order:** (Letter first then number)

```
SELECT 
*
FROM YOUR_TABLE
ORDER BY CAST(player_number AS UNSIGNED),player_number
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following;)

```
select player_number
from table1
order by if(player_number != '0' and (player_number + 1) = 1, 0, (player_number + 1)), player_number
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ab08/1)**